# equivalent of multiprocessing.Pool.map (or starmap) that calls an iterator only when needed?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Consider this problem.

I have a module containing the following functions:

- a calculation function, which:

  - takes a very consistent amount of time to run
  - requires some input parameters
  - writes some output to the filesystem
  - also returns a value
- an inputs iterator, which:

  - when iterated over, will return a tuple containing inputs to the calculation function
  - takes a negligible amount of time to run compared to the calculation function
  - on the *i*th iteration, it needs to read data from the filesystem that was written by the calculation function during the (*i* − *M*)th iteration (for *i* > *M*)

It ought to be possible to parallelise the calculation function using a pool of size *N* where *N < M*, provided that the inputs iterator is not called for the *i*th time until the pool is ready to launch the *i*th worker.  (Assume that the code needed to manage the parallelisation also takes negligible time compared to the calculation function.)

In this example (`mymodel.py`):

- The calculation function is called `is_warmest`. It takes just over 1 second to run (dominated by an explicit `time.sleep(1)`). It writes to the filesystem using files in a `data` subdirectory. For convenience, it also sometimes prints out a message for demonstration purposes.
- The inputs generator is called `gen_inputs`.
- *M* = 12, and *N* = 6
- `gen_inputs` starts by removing output from previous runs, so that the code can be conveniently retested.

The example code is shown towards the end of the question.

First, I try running the code sequentially using the following main program.

`main.py`

```
from mymodel import gen_inputs, is_warmest

print([is_warmest(*inputs) for inputs in gen_inputs()])
```

This produces the following output to the screen as well as the expected output to the filesystem.

```
$ time python3 main.py 
January 2010 is the warmest January since 2010
January 2011 is not the warmest January since 2010
January 2012 is not the warmest January since 2010
January 2013 is the warmest January since 2010
January 2014 is the warmest January since 2010
January 2015 is the warmest January since 2010
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]

real    1m12.146s
user    0m0.057s
sys 0m0.019s
```

To parallelise it with 6 workers, first let us consider a simple pool, which is capable of launching *N* processes, but it does not implement any communication with these processes, so it provides a `map` function which returns `None`.  The code for the pool class (`mypool.py`) is at the end of the question.  I run it using the following main program:

```
from mymodel import gen_inputs, is_warmest
from mypool import SimplePool

pool = SimplePool(6)
print(pool.starmap(is_warmest, gen_inputs()))
```

It completes in 1/6th of the time as expected, and again, it produces the correct output to the screen and to the filesystem, except that the return value is now `None`.

```
$ time python3 main2.py 
January 2010 is the warmest January since 2010
January 2011 is not the warmest January since 2010
January 2012 is not the warmest January since 2010
January 2013 is the warmest January since 2010
January 2014 is the warmest January since 2010
January 2015 is the warmest January since 2010
None

real    0m12.213s
user    0m0.606s
sys 0m0.216s
```

Finally, let us consider an attempt to parallelise the code using `multiprocessing.Pool`, which should if successful actually return a list of the return values from the calculation function.  Here is the main program:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from mymodel import gen_inputs, is_warmest

pool = Pool(6)
print(pool.starmap(is_warmest, gen_inputs()))
```

This fails, because `pool.starmap` is invoking `list()` on the iterator at the very start, before any of the calculation has run, so that the iterator is called repeatedly at the start, before the data on which later iterations depend is available on the filesystem, so it gives a `FileNotFoundError`.

```
$ time python3 main3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main3.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(mypool.starmap(is_warmest, gen_inputs()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 274, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 376, in _map_async
    iterable = list(iterable)
  File "/path/to/mymodel.py", line 46, in gen_inputs
    data.append(read_data(year - 1, month))
  File "/path/to/mymodel.py", line 14, in read_data
    with open(get_filename(year, month)) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/temp_2010_1'

real    0m0.168s
user    0m0.106s
sys 0m0.024s
```

The question then is whether an equivalent of `multiprocessing.Pool.starmap` (or `multiprocessing.Pool.map`) exists, which can be given an iterator as its second argument and will only call it when it is ready to launch the worker which will use the value returned by the iterator.

A further desirable enhancement would be if you could supply a separate callback function which will return a value to say whether the iterator is ready to be called, and if this returns a false value then the pool class should back off for a while and not call the iterator until it has tried again later and this has returned a true value.  For example if you could do something like:

```
def mycalc(x):
    ....

class MyInputsGen():

    def __init__(self):
        self.next_input_file = ....

    def am_i_ready(self):
        return os.path.exists(self.next_input_file)

    def generator(self):
        while ...:
            with open(self.next_input_file) as f:
               answer = ...
            self.next_input_file = ....  # for next iteration
            yield answer

my_inputs_gen = MyInputsGen()
pool = ...
pool.map(myfunc, my_inputs_gen.generator(), is_ready=my_inputs_gen.am_i_ready)
```

so that it never attempts to read input data until it is already guaranteed that it will exist, even though the input data might not all be available at the start when `pool.map` is called.

---

### Test code

`mymodel.py`

```
import os
import math
import glob
import time

def get_filename(year, month):
    return "data/temp_{}_{}".format(year, month)

def write_data(year, month, data):
    with open(get_filename(year, month), "w") as f:
        f.write(str(data) + "\n")

def read_data(year, month):
    with open(get_filename(year, month)) as f:
        return float(f.read())

def run_model(year, month):
    "run model, store the output and return the monthly temperature"
    time.sleep(1)
    x = (year - 2012) / 2.
    temp = x + x**2  + 10 * math.sin(month * math.pi / 6)
    write_data(year, month, temp)
    return temp

def is_warmest(year, month, previous_maximum):
    "run the model for the given month, and say if it is the warmest on record"
    temp = run_model(year, month)
    answer = previous_maximum == None or temp > previous_maximum
    if month == 1:
        print("January {} {} the warmest January since 2010".format(
            year, "is" if answer else "is not"))
    return answer

def gen_inputs():
    "loop over years and months, reading the inputs for is_warmest"
    data = []
    if not os.path.isdir("data"):
        os.mkdir("data")
    for file in glob.glob("data/temp_*_*"):
        os.remove(file)
    for year in range(2010, 2016):
        for month in range(1, 13):
            if year == 2010:
                previous_max = None
            else:
                data.append(read_data(year - 1, month))
                previous_max = max(data[month-1 : : 12])
            yield (year, month, previous_max)
```

`mypool.py`

```
import os
import sys

class SimplePool:
    """
    a simple pool that runs up to <n> processes in parallel, 
    but it doesn't communicate with them
    """
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def starmap(self, func, it):
        n_running = 0
        for values in it:
            while n_running == self.size:
                os.wait()
                n_running -= 1
            if os.fork() == 0:
                func(*values)
                sys.exit(0)
            n_running += 1
        while n_running > 0:
            os.wait()
            n_running -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap):

> A lazier version of `map()`.
>
> The `chunksize` argument is the same as the one used by the `map()`
>   method. For very long iterables using a large value for `chunksize` can
>   make the job complete much faster than using the default value of 1.
>
> Also if `chunksize` is 1 then the `next()` method of the iterator returned
>   by the imap() method has an optional timeout parameter: next(timeout)
>   will raise multiprocessing.TimeoutError if the result cannot be
>   returned within timeout seconds.

What is meant by a "A lazier version of `map`" is that it does not try to consume your entire iterable at the start (via `list()`). Instead, it consumes it one (or `chunksize`) items at a time, and only pulls more items once its done with the previous chunk.